# Is there an absolute column limit for Google's Charts?

Tags: google-visualization

I have finally gotten a column chart working for my data set. However, it only outputs fifteen columns, and the data set has 36 columns. It will output fifteen columns (or less if I limit the set to only items that are non-zero...but my boss wants *all* of the data shown) no matter what width the graph is set to.

Is there an absolute hard-coded column limit for graphs made by Google's Charts API, and if not, is there a way I can tell the graph to output everything?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (I successfully plotted 26 different data series on a column chart with 10 categories of data). Please provide some sample data that reproduces your problem.

Comment: There is no limit to the number of columns of data allowed.  It is possible to run into display limits (where the minimum space required to display the data is greater than the width or height (depending on chart type) of the chart) that would truncate the quantity of displayed data.  As an example, if you had a ColumnChart with 10 data series and 80 rows of data (800 data points), but was only 400 pixels wide, the width of each column would have to be 1/2 pixel to fit them all (too small to draw), so the chart would draw the first 5 columns 1 pixel wide at each point and truncate the last 5.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this myself, almost 7 years after the original problem report.  Columns representing the right-side of my data are being silently un-drawn.

Let's look at the big picture.  Somebody provides a charting library.  They should be expected to show the data as best they can.  In the case of a column table, that would be to show the first and last columns, and then choose which intermediate columns to show based on an algorithm that takes available pixels into account.  It would then let the user zoom in to see the full set of columns within the selected range.  This gives the developer using the chart the freedom to show an unlimited amount of data and not have to worry that someday columns at the end are simply not drawn.

Google is already choosing to not print some of the column labels due to space constraints, so they're already halfway to understanding the big picture.

*Nowhere* in the documentation does it explain this truncation of columns due to space constraints, or for any other chart type that I've seen.  But you sure can choose your background colors in great levels of detail.

If I had known this restriction going in, I would have chosen a different chart package and not wasted my time.  My choices now are to break my "Lifetime" data into yearly graphs that fit in the available space, which is clunky as hell, or migrate to a different chart package.  Thanks Google.  :^(

P.S. I tried to post this as a comment to the OP, but after using SO for years I don't have enough points...